# Como mostrar um número separado por ponto a cada 3 casas?

Tags: javascript

Como posso formatar valores dessa forma: `1.000` ou `150.000` ou `42.000` ?

Meu código é esse:

```
var f02 = 42000;
console.log(parseInt(f02));
```

Preciso que a formatação da variável `f02` fique assim: `42.000`, e quando o numero for maior a formatação se adapte, exemplo: `150.000` ou `1.000.000`

Comment: Você quer um separador. Não é pra transformar um número inteiro em real, certo?

Comment: usa o `.toLocaleString()`

Comment: Isso @jbueno, um separador...

Comment: Você vai precisar apresentar este valor como `string`. Um inteiro não vai te permitir fazer isso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma opção é o método [`Number.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```js
function formatarValor(valor) {
    return valor.toLocaleString('pt-BR');
}

console.log(formatarValor(42000));
console.log(formatarValor(150000));
console.log(formatarValor(1000000));
```

Usando o *locale* `pt-BR`, os números serão formatados como você quer, com `.`, se você quiser usar `,`, use outro *locale*, por exemplo: `en-US`.

Se você precisar exibir a parte fracionária, use o parâmetro `minimumFractionDigits` seguido da quantidade mínima de dígitos:

```
function formatarValor(valor) {
    return valor.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 } );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Segue exemplo simples para colocar `.` a cada três dígitos e no final coloca uma virgula:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f "${1}" ]
then
   echo -e "Sintaxe : $0 [ number ]\n"
   exit 1
else
   valor="$1"
fi

     num="`echo "${valor}" | sed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\>/,&/;ta'`"
     num="`echo ${num} | sed 's:,:.:g'`"
qtde_cps="`echo ${num} | sed 's:\.:\n:g' | wc -l`"
     ult="`expr ${qtde_cps} - 1`"
  inicio="`echo ${num} | cut -d\. -f1-${ult}`"
   final="`echo ${num} | cut -d\. -f${qtde_cps}`"

echo "${num}"
echo -e "${inicio},${final}\n"
```